# Length of a list in O(1)

Tags: data-structures, graph, linked-list, time-complexity

I'm currently writing my master's thesis about a graph algorithm. I’m getting a graph passed as an adjacency list. Then I save it in different data structures to be able to perform the operations in the algorithm in O (1). However, I also need to find out and save the degree of each node. The length of the adjacency lists corresponds to the degree of the vertices. How can I find out the length of the adjacency lists in O(1)? I can also add/use another data structure.

Thank you for any help!

Lisa

Comment: _I'm currently writing my master's thesis about a graph algorithm_ and you are asking for an algorithm? you are the one supposed to tell us how to do it (also, how can a List tell you the adjacent nodes? a list of what?)

Comment: I edited my question. I'm not asking for an algorithm. I'm asking for help with one of the operations. The neighboring nodes of each node are stored in the adjacency lists.

Comment: Well, it depends on _how_ are you implementing the adjacency list. A list data structure typically has a field storing its length, so obtaining it is O(1) Or you can keep track of it in a separate field. What language are you using? What list implementation? so many required details are missing from your question...

Comment: please provide some implementation detail, at least a pseudo code of what you have, and example input and its desiderd output

Comment: It's a theoretical work. I don't have to program anything. I am given an array with all nodes and this has pointers to a LinkedList with the associated neighbors. In the code, I look at an edge between two nodes and have to decide which of the two nodes has the smaller degree in order to continue working with this one. Therefore, I need to know the degree of each node beforehand.

Comment: Okay, now I had an idea. Maybe you can tell me if it would work that way. I don't necessarily need the structure of the adjacency lists. Since the pointers in the list bother me, I would like to use a different data structure for this. If I alternatively create dynamic arrays instead of linked lists in the adjacency "lists" for each node and declare a counter that counts each inserted element, then at the end I would have the node degree through the counter, no more pointers and I don't have to know the size beforehand, as with normal arrays, correctly ?

Comment: Dynamic arrays would be the right thing to use here compare to a linked list. They would give you their size in O(1), if they are correctly implemented which corresponds to the degree of that node. I wouldn't use them directly though, to get the degree. I would abstract this away as a method/property that takes a node and returns its degree. The method then would be responsible for querying the length of the dynamic array for that particular node in the adj list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So I can get the size of a dynamic array in O(1)? Then I wouldn't need the counter at all. And what exactly do you mean by the method?